# Problema para vincular duas structs em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

O programa é sobre um banco, preciso de duas structs (uma de cliente e uma de contas), o titular da conta tem que ser vinculado com algum cliente. Porém na função Add_Conta, não estou conseguindo fazer esse vinculo, preciso de uma maneira que aponte para o local onde o cliente esta cadastrado, ou de alguma sugestão de como eu poderia fazer.
Mais adiante vou precisar imprimir os clientes de uma agencia, então eu precisaria de filtrar dados das duas structs.

````
//Declara��o structs - Cliente e Conta
typedef struct
{
  char nome[100];
  int RG;
  char endereco[200];
  int telefone;
  float renda;
  int tipo_cliente; //1-private, 2-alta renda, 3-varejo
  union
  {
      int cpf;
      int cnpj;
  } cpf_cnpj;
  int num_cl;
} Cliente;
Cliente cliente[MAX_CLIENTES];
char nome[100];
char endereco[200];

int posicao;

typedef struct
{
  int Numero_Conta; //deve ser unico e gerado pelo programa
  int Agencia;
  float Saldo_Conta;
  int Tipo_Conta;          // 1- Conta corrente 2-Conta poupanca 3- conta-salario
  struct Cliente *Titular; // titulares (deve estar vinculado aos clientes cadastrados)

} Dados_Contas;
Dados_Contas contas[MAX_CLIENTES];


void Add_Conta(int j, int num)
{
  int id;
  printf("Preencha os dados a seguir: \n \n");
  printf("Agencia: \n");
  scanf("%d%*c", &contas[j].Agencia);
  contas[j].Numero_Conta = num;
  printf("O sistema definiu o seguinte numero para a conta: %d \n", num);
  printf("Saldo da conta: \n");
  scanf("%f%*c", &contas[j].Saldo_Conta);
  printf("Tipo da conta: \n 1- CONTA-CORRENTE \n 2- CONTA POUPANCA \n 3- CONTA-SALARIO \n");
  scanf("%d%*c", &contas[j].Tipo_Conta);
  printf("Qual o numero (identificador) do cliente titular? ");
  scanf("%d", &id);
  // contas[id]->Titular=&cliente[id];1
}

  ```
````

Comment: Poste um programa completo, algo compilável. Ajude os outros a ajudar você...
No seu programa Cliente é uma estrutura. Um nome. E assim cliente é Clientes[MAX_CLIENTES]; Então ao declarar Titular como um ponteiro para um Cliente não é uma struct. Use apenas Cliente* Titular

Comment: Na proxima vez eu posto o codigo completo, obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente está sofrendo na hora de de-referenciar um endereço.

Veja esse trecho do código:

```
contas[j]->Titular = &cliente[id];
```

Com o operador `->` você de-referencia um endereço, isso diz que o código deve checar o endereço que está gravado no ponteiro, e continuar o acesso a partir desse endereço.

O valor de `contas[id]` não é um endereço, ele é do tipo `Dados_Contas`, não do tipo `Dados_Contas*`, o que significa que você não deveria estar de-referenciando ele. Deveria ser:

```
contas[j].Titular = &cliente[id];
```

Agora o atributo `Titular` é um ponteiro do tipo `struct Cliente*`, ele grava um endereço, e aí sim faria sentido de-referenciar esse endereço para acessar uma das propriedades dessa estrutura, como seria o caso:

```
printf("Nome do cliente: %s \n", contas[id].Titular->nome);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! muito obrigada!